# How to map out an array that is taken from props

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to map out an array that was passed into the component via props. For example, I have a ViewPosts page and I call the Comments component by passing the post as a prop into the component. The goal is to take the array out of the props and map it out so that I can use the post id in an axios call to get all the comments for the post. Then, once i fetch the comments,  I need to be able to take the user id out of the "Comments" array and make another axios call to get the user's name (who left the comment), since the backend developer did not include that in the array. I also need to be able to take the comment id to make an axios call to delete the comment. My code is as follows

I successfully mapped out the array, however, i mapped it out in the return statement and therefore cannot use the data in my axios calls since it is outside of the return statement. The codes are attatched.

ViewPosts.js

{data && }

Comments.js

export default function Comments(props) {

```
const [comments, setComments] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:6006/api/v1/posts/${props.post._id}/comments`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Pulling Comments Frm::: ", res.data.data);
        setComments(res.data.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("err::  ", err));
  }, []); 
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState("")
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:6006/api/v1/users/${comments.user}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("err::  ", err));
  }, []); 
  return (
    <div>
        {comments?.map((comment) => (
            <>
                <Typography> <h3> {user.name}: {comment.text} </h3>  </Typography> 
            </>
        ))}
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know i might have to do something with promise.all combined with array.map

Comment: View Posts is supposed to be : {data && <Comments post = {data} />

Answer (score 0):

Axios calls are async so the user api call will be called before your comments are fetched.

You can add `comments` to the User api useEffect so it would look like
`React.useEffect(() => { ... }, [comments]);`
This makes it so the call is made whenever comments changes